# Mudar local de armazenamento no laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

O local atual de armazenamento do laravel é */laravel/storage/app/public*. Como faço para mudar para */laravel/public*. Tentei editar o filesystems.php mas não tive sucesso:

Função store do controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $paciente = new Paciente($input);
    $paciente->save();

    if(empty($request->arquivo))
    {    
        return redirect()->action('PacienteController@index');
    } 
    else
    {
        $file = $request->arquivo;
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = $request->file('arquivo')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'upload');

        $arquivo = new Arquivo();
        $arquivo->paciente_id = $paciente->id;
        $arquivo->nome = $fileName;
        $arquivo->save();

        return redirect()->action('PacienteController@index');
    }   
}
```

Filesystems.php

```
return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
| by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
| based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
|
*/

'default' => 'local',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
| reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
| will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
|
*/

'cloud' => 's3',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Filesystem Disks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
| may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
| been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
|
| Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
|
*/

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

    'upload' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

],

];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crie outra configuração, exemplo ***`pictures`***, em sua chave `root` utilize a função [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-public-path) que indica a pasta `public` do seu projeto:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => 'local',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => 's3',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'pictures' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Para gravar as imagens utilize:

```
$result = $request->file('image');
$ext = $result->getClientOriginalExtension();
$result->storeAs('images', uniqid().'.'.$ext, 'pictures');
```

<sub>**Observação:** *no código o último paramento indica a configuração criada no arquivo* `filesystems.php`</sub>

***ou***

```
$result->store('images','pictures');
```

<sub>**Observação:** *no código o último paramento indica a configuração criada no arquivo* `filesystems.php`</sub>

---

Se não quiser utilizar nada disso pode fazer pelo tradicional `move` que grava diretamente na pasta `public` (no caso exemplo foi colocado na pasta `public/images`):

```
$result = $request->file('image');
$ext = $result->getClientOriginalExtension();
$result->move('images', uniqid().'.'.$ext);
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Filesystem / Cloud Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem)
- [Filesystem / Cloud Storage - File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-uploads)
- [Helper Functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers)
- [Helper Functions - public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-public-path)

Comment: Editei o post com as alterações e com o meu método completo. Ao tentar fazer o upload ocorre o erro: Driver [] is not supported.

Comment: @Marcelo é um erro na configuração. De uma conferida.

Comment: Dei uma olhada mas não encontrei o erro.

Comment: Estranho @Marcelo é assim mesmo que faz

Comment: Antes de tudo havia dado o comando php artisan storage:link, isso pode influenciar em algo? Não sei se essa é a melhor solução mas estou tentando isso pq minha aplicação faz o upload e download de arquivos. No meu computador tudo funciona normalmente, mas na hospedagem do hostgator so consigo fazer o upload, o download da erro. Coloquei a aplicação do laravel antes do diretório public_html e copiei o conteúdo da public do laravel para a public_html.

Comment: Todos os arquivos são copiados menos o link simbólico do storage, informa que o arquivo já existe. Por isso estou tentando mudar o diretório de upload para a pasta public do laravel.

Comment: Funcionou após php artisan cache:clear e config:cache. Obrigado.

Comment: Marcelo, conseguiu resolver o problema da pasta publica? estou com o mesmo problema, ele copia o arquivo para storage mas não aponta para a pasta public_html, poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Não precisa alterar nada no seu código.

Se você estiver usando Linux (ou o [Homestead<sup>en</sup>](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)) basta executar um comando que faz um [*symlink*<sup>en</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) (link simbólico) entre o `/storage/app/public` e `/public/storage` e assim você pode usar o disk `public` sem problemas:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Veja isso na [documentação<sup>en</sup>](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#configuration).

Dá pra fazer *symlink* também no Windows através do comando `mklink` e o [Laravel já suporta isso](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L222), só que isso é restrito para usuários administradores no sistema.

Felizmente na próxima atualização do sistema, a *Creators Update* isso [será simplificado<sup>en</sup>](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/#ZxgMZaT4Vzxx2Hx0.97) e até usuários não administradores poderão fazer isso.

Comment: Fiz isso e funciona no meu computador. O problema é que fui hospedar a aplicação e deu erro ao tentar fazer o download do arquivo (o upload funciona), creio que por ele não estar na public_html da hospedagem, diretório acima da aplicação. Por esse motivo estou tentando tirar o upload da pasta storage e colocar na public.

Comment: Não sei se tem uma forma melhor de funcionar na hospedagem, mas foi a alternativa que pensei.

Comment: Geralmente as hospedagens vão te limar demais Marcelo. Recomendo sair delas o quanto antes e procurar algo onde vc tem mais controle do web server. Opções não faltam e tem pra todos os bolsos, como heroku, digital ocean, AWS, azure e assim vai.

Comment: Realmente é mais uma das opções +1 pela resposta